# How to set oxygen-gtk font preferences

Tags: 12.04, themes, fonts

So I upgrade to 12.04 (clean install) from 11.04.
I got used to many things in 11.04, one of which is this great work [oxygen-gtk](https://launchpad.net/gtk2-engines-oxygen)

I knew there is gtk3 version, and expected everything to be smooth for some reason. Unfortunately, I soon found out that I'll need not only gtk3 version of this package, but also gtk2 version. This is my issue:

[oxygen-gtk3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/oxygen-gtk3) uses white font color on light background

- How can I set it to use black font?

Comment: You might consider editing the title so its not Theme specific (to be helpful to others) How do set GTK theme font color Preferences?  The reason I suggest you emphasize color is that there are much simpler solutions for changing fonts there size and weight in My Unity. Ubuntu Tweak or Advanced Gnome Settings etc

Comment: I'm not sure about that, as oxygen-gtk is not classical theme but depends on special library, thou maybe you are right, maybe it can be issue with other themes, but I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided answer is not enough. Look at this bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=299001

So instead explaining how wrong is answered approach I'd suggest to other users to use git version of oxygen-gtk with provided patch, until gtk3 hype calms down. All above things or tweaking gtk.css is wrong approach, and I hope people responsible for packing this theme read this, for everyone satisfaction

Answer (score 1):

There is kdeglobals file in gtk-3 theme folder - under [WM] section there is setting activeForeground. That setting affects font color

In addition , I was previously successful using this method for the Malys Theme *(it may be that some themes are compiled differently)*

Go to /usr/share/themes/theme name/gtk-3.0 where there are are .css files 
You can modify font colors in these files through gedit.

- Make a back up copy of the .css file before you start (it case things
  go wrong, you can then revert back)
- Modify the gtk.css file in gedit.
- Put in the hexadecimal code of the color you want  ([This
  might help](http://html-color-codes.com/))

**Only do this if you are comforatable editing CSS files.""

Comment: I opened it already - there is no setting for font color. I even copied Ambiance `gtk.css` contents in oxygen (altogether with include files) as there were font settings, but without success, so I revert it to original.

Comment: Strange, I answered the question from the top of my head as I did this successfully a few months ago with my favorite Malys theme as I had exactly the same issue. I will check again but unfortunately it won't be until later.  Hopefully someone can answer in the interim.

Comment: @zetah You might find this article useful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492861/gtk-change-font-and-font-color-for-an-application

Comment: There is `kdeglobals` file in gtk-3 theme folder - under `[WM]` section there is setting `activeForeground`. That setting affects font color. Stephen if you edit your answer and include this finding, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I trust you found the atricle useful then (Thanks!)